# Error SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint when i try to do some register from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

***I have some insert's in sql , but know i try to do it from laravel an set the id to 1, but there are some registers before that are the registers from sql,how can i do a register after the one's that are from the insert's in sql, its for school***

***Error :`Key (id_evento)=(1) already exists`***
***Laravel 6.0***

- Below i will let the insert in sql,my `store function()` i want to insert from both of them without problems with the id's

***Insert in sql***

```sql
INSERT INTO Evento (ID_Evento,Nombre_Evento,Fecha,FK_Lugar)
VALUES
(1,'Econobirra','2019-08-20',null),
(2,'Cervezanal','2019-09-29',null),
(3,'Birractubre Fest','2020-10-17',null);
```

*** `Store function()`***

```sql
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $evento = new Evento();
        $evento->nombre_evento = $request->nombre_evento;
        $evento->fecha = $request->fecha;
        $evento->save();
        return back()->with('Evento Agregado!');
    }
```

***Model of evento***

```sql
class Evento extends Model
{   protected $primaryKey = 'id_evento';
    protected $table = 'evento';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['id_evento','nombre_evento', 'fecha'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: make the Id in the table auto increment and do pass it in the sql query.  ID_Evento is your forign key ?

Comment: ID_Evento is my primary key and it is autoincremented but doens't work in any ways

Comment: do not send it in the query. use it as below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your sql query be like

```
INSERT INTO Evento (Nombre_Evento,Fecha,FK_Lugar)
VALUES
('Econobirra','2019-08-20',null),
('Cervezanal','2019-09-29',null),
('Birractubre Fest','2020-10-17',null);
```

Comment: ID_Evento is my primary key cant be null or ' '

Comment: please see updated answer then you don't need to send the ID_Evento

Comment: also could you please give your table structure

Answer (score 0):

set: protected $primaryKey = 'ID_Evento'; in your Evento model

Comment: Yes i have it that way

Comment: set 
`protected $fillable = [
    'Nombre_Evento',
    'Fecha',
    'FK_Lugar',
]`

and remove "id_evento" in it.
`protected $fillable = ['id_evento','nombre_evento', 'fecha'];`

Comment: remove "public $incrementing = false;"